# TTL By Document with Cosmos Db Mongo API

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

In Cosmos Db, I am using a document level Time to Live (TTL) and Cosmos does not appear to be expiring documents. Does this feature work in Cosmos Db using MongoDB API? If it does, what am I missing?

- I am using Cosmos Db with the MongoDB API.
- A "ttl" field is set in each document for my collection.
- In Azure, Time to Live is set to "On (no default)" for my collection.
- I am doing this without the emulator because the emulator defaults to the SQL API. In the emulator, I see "_ts" set and I do not see this field in Azure.
- I can switch to collection level expiration by setting Time to Live to "On" and documents expire as expected. When I do this, my "ttl" field is ignored and the value I set for "second(s)" in Azure is followed. I still see my "ttl" field in the document.

Although I don't see a "_ts" field in my documents, an article about indexing mentions that it is a reserved property. This makes be think that it is set behind the scenes and it is not returned in queries.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-indexing
>   "_ts is a Cosmos DB-specific field and is not accessible from MongoDB clients. It is a reserved (system) property that contains the timestamp of the document's last modification."

**Update:**
I checked the MongoDB support page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support) and it indicates that collection level TTL is available and says nothing about document level.

> Azure Cosmos DB supports a relative time-to-live (TTL) based on the timestamp of the document. TTL can be enabled for MongoDB API collections through the Azure portal.

**Update:**
My Azure Portal Preview Features now show this:
[image: Cosmos DB Preview Features]

Comment: How do you get to that menu to enable per-document TTL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got document level Time to Live working in Cosmos Db using MongoDb API. I had to ask help from Microsoft support to get this working. Response from Microsoft Big data team was following.

> Before enabling Document level  TTL feature ,  I would like to
>   clarify following about Document TTL feature details here.
>
> The TTL feature is controlled by TTL properties at two levels -
>   Collection level and the Document level.
>
> Right now per Document level TTL for MongoDB accounts are not
>   available by default. However, we can enable this feature for specific
>   customers and this feature is set at an account level.
>
> TTL is at a document level but the feature is enabled at an account
>   level which means for all collections under the account, if there is a
>   document with a TTL set, it will take effect. For other collections,
>   if the TTL value is not set for each document, it would not be
>   affected.
>
> You needs to have an index on the _ts field for this to work.
>
> To summarize this : - This feature works at  Cosmos DB account level. 
>   We need to enable Document TTL feature in Cosmos DB backend on our
>   side.

Comment: This is what I was looking for! I went ahead and implemented at the collection level due to time constraints.